# Multiple colors in background (transition)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtstylesheets

Is there a way to have transitioning colors as background in PyQt?
I tried using CSS's linear-gradient, which doesn't work

```
stylesheet = ("QWidget { background-color : linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%);}")
```

How do I get it to work for me?

Comment: While Qt stylesheets use standard syntax, their naming convention is slightly different in specific cases and you cannot expect to use normal CSS syntax transparently. Please carefully read the [reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) (there's a chapter dedicated to [gradients](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#gradient)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I manually specified the start and stop coordinates of the gradient using `x1, x2` instead of `to right` and added the `stop` keywords.

```
stylesheet = "QWidget {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, x2: 1, stop: 0 red, stop: 1 blue)}"
```

[image]

Or did you want a sharp transition like this?

```
stylesheet = "QWidget {background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, x2:1, stop: 0.49 red, stop: 0.51 blue)}"
```

[image]